# Validating Textbox is not Empty with Labels and hiding label once text is entered

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

I have a simple inventory application that I am working on to help myself learn C#.  I have a registration Windows Form that will add a user to a database so that they can login to the application.  It works.  However I am now working on adding some textbox validation.  I have three text boxes that will populate a label beside them if they are empty.  However, I cannot figure out how to get the label to be null or hide after text is entered.  Any suggestions?

Here is my code on the createButton_Click method:

```
 private void createButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|FAMDatabase.accdb");
        OleDbCommand fcmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Login([UserName],[Password])" + "values(@username,@password)", con);
        fcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", newUserTextBox.Text);
        fcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", newPasswordTextBox.Text);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newUserTextBox.Text))
        {
            reqName.Text = ("Please enter a User Name");
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newPasswordTextBox.Text))
        {
            reqPW.Text = ("Please enter a Password");
        }
        else if (newPasswordTextBox.Text != newPasswordTextBox2.Text)
        {
            reqPW2.Text = ("Passwords Do Not Match");
        }
        else
        {
            con.Open();
            int i = fcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(
                "User Successfully Created",
                "",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Information,
                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure if I follow your comment:

> *I cannot figure out how to get the label to be null or hide after text is entered*

Making the label null is possible, however to hide the label you can simply set the text of the label to an empty string. Example: `reqName.Text = "";`.

You can set the labels after the user presses the create button, and this appears to be what the posted code is doing. However if you want these labels to hide/display as the user types into the text boxes but BEFORE the user presses the create button, then you will need to set up some events for each text box to make the appropriate label changes after the user finishes typing into one of the text boxes. A convenient event for this is the `TextChanged` event for each text box. Once the text changes, you can set the appropriate label for that text box.

Using this, the other thing I would recommend is not mixing the user validation with the inserting into the database. Example: At the beginning of the button click method, you set up the parameters to insert into the database using values that have not be validated yet. This is unnecessary if any of the text boxes text is invalid. So separating this user validation and inserting into the database will make things easier and more logical.

Below is a method `ValidUserInput` that checks the input from the user for validity and returns true if the data is valid or false if not. The method also returns a string message to indicate what the problem was if the data was invalid. Then in the button click event, you can check for validity and if valid add it to the database. I commented out adding to the database as it appears this may be working for you. I also added a results label to indicate what the problem was if the user input was invalid.

Three events are used to update the labels as the user types. Two helper methods: `ClearLabels` and `SetLabels`  are used to clear and set the labels on the form. Hope this helps.

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  ClearLabels();
  SetLabels();
}

private void createButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string statusString = "";

  if (!ValidUserInput(out statusString)) {
    lblStatus.Text = statusString;
  }
  else {
    ///OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|FAMDatabase.accdb");
    //OleDbCommand fcmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Login([UserName],[Password])" + "values(@username,@password)", con);
    //fcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", newUserTextBox.Text);
    //fcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", newPasswordTextBox.Text);
    //con.Open();
    //int i = fcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("User Successfully Created","", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
    //this.Close();
  }
}

private bool ValidUserInput(out string message) {
  ClearLabels();
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newUserTextBox.Text)) {
    reqName.Text = ("Please enter a User Name");
    message = "UserName can not be blank!";
    return false;
  }
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newPasswordTextBox.Text)) {
    reqPW.Text = ("Please enter a Password");
    message = "Password can not be blank!";
    return false;
  }
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newPasswordTextBox2.Text)) {
    reqPW2.Text = ("Please enter a Password ");
    message = "Password verification can not be blank!";
    return false;
  }
  if (newPasswordTextBox.Text != newPasswordTextBox2.Text) {
    reqPW.Text = ("Passwords Do Not Match");
    reqPW2.Text = ("Passwords Do Not Match");
    message = "Password must match!";
    return false;
  }
  message = "Valid User Input";
  return true;
}

private void ClearLabels() {
  reqName.Text = "";
  reqPW.Text = "";
  reqPW2.Text = "";
  lblStatus.Text = "";
}

private void SetLabels() {
  ClearLabels();
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newUserTextBox.Text)) {
    reqName.Text = "Please enter a User Name";
  }
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newPasswordTextBox.Text)) {
    reqPW.Text = "Please enter a Password";
  }
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newPasswordTextBox2.Text)) {
    reqPW2.Text = "Please enter a Password";
  }
  lblStatus.Text = "Enter userName and password";
}

private void newUserTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newUserTextBox.Text)) {
    reqName.Text = "Please enter a User Name";
  }
  else {
    reqName.Text = "";
  }
}

private void newPasswordTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newPasswordTextBox.Text)) {
    reqPW.Text = "Please enter a Password";
  } else {
    reqPW.Text = "";
  }
}

private void newPasswordTextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newPasswordTextBox2.Text)) {
    reqPW2.Text = "Please enter a Password";
  } else {
    reqPW2.Text = "";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I suppose to clarify, I can get the validation to work fine.  But when a user goes and fills in the text box for the user name for example the error label still shows the "Please enter a User Name" message.  Im guessing I will need to use a textChanged event?

Comment: @LearningCSharp Your comment: _I can get the validation to work fine. But when a user goes and fills in the text box for the user name for example the error label still shows the "Please enter a User Name" message._ So It works fine except??? The code I posted in my answer does as you are asking. Once the user starts typing into the `newUserTextBox`… the `reqName`  label's text “Please enter a user Name” will not display. It will continue to NOT display until the user deletes the text in the `newUserTextBox`. I am guessing I may be missing something.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by removing the private void SetLabels() method.  With it, it was setting the labels to the errors as the form loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the css attribute `visiblity: hidden;`, the css attribute `display: none;`, or you could simply change the text to empty string.